# FTP upload wrong permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, permissions, ftp

Added "youri" to the www-data group

```
grep youri /etc/group

www-data:x:33:youri
youri:x:1004:
```

When i upload something with FTP, the file permission is `-rw-------`

```
ls -all

total 176
drwxr-xr-x 2 youri youri   4096 feb 25 12:38 .
dr-xr-xr-x 3 youri youri   4096 feb 25 12:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 youri youri     17 feb 25 12:27 index.php
-rw------- 1 youri youri 164655 feb 25 12:24 test.pdf (uploaded with FTP)
```

The file index.php is created by nano and changed the permissions by `sudo chown youri:youri index.php`

When i access my website it shows me the index.php but /test.pdf gives me an "Permission denied" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver has no permission to read the file.

Normally, an ftp server has a configuration value called "umask" which is a value defining what permissions NOT to grant (the binary inverse of the value you would give to chmod)

For a better security, most ftp servers like vsftp ship with a default umask of 055 or 077

As you can see, your index.php is not executable. Although it technically is just *read*, semantically the script is being *executed* by your webserver. And the webserver runs as the user *www-data*.

To have this work, change the following:

```
- Make youri's default group www-data: usermod -g www-data youri
- Change /etc/vsftpd.conf and set a umask of 022
- Restart vsftpd
- chmod 755 index.php (or delete it and upload it again)
```

Comment: Changed default group to www-data, set local_umask to 022 and restarted vsftpd, after uploading permissions are: ```--w----r--```

Comment: weird behaviour. some questions: 

1. did you delete the file in advance? 
2. is the file now owned by youri:www-data?
3. what happens when you chmod the index.php manually?

Comment: After a chmod 755 it works, but i dont wanna chmod every time? @Psi

Comment: ```--w------- 1 youri www-data   16 feb 25 13:03 index.php```

Comment: Was trying with ```file_open_mode=xxx``` and without file_open_mode it works now. Thanks